# How to write an ASP.NET ef core sql query in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

Im using javascript to draw my UI and implement a map from the Google Maps API, however, I have an MSSQL database connected to an ASP.NET program that contains the map which is run in a cshtml page, I managed to get a SQL query working in c# however it would make my life so much easier if I could generate SQL queries in my javascript code instead, is there any way I could translate this (or equivalent) code:

```
    string fishName;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("sqlConnection");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT minLength FROM Fish";
    fishName = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    conn.Close();
```

into javascript?

I know I could use `Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)` and it makes it much easier, however, the amount of marks I lose out on if I use this solution is far too large.

I cant even remember what I have tried it has taken so long, I am quite new to ASP and JavaScript and have been scouring the internet for actual days trying any solution I could find.

Comment: You cannot use databases in client-side using JavaScript. If you want to work with SQL using JavaScript, you will need to implement a Node.js application and create an API to fetch this data to your client application using HTTP.

Comment: It's kinda dangerous too, since an evil entity might be able to inject sql code directly from web browser. As above poster says, node.js is how you usually do this stuff